# Installation of Rstudio for ubuntu

Tags: rstudio, rstudio-server, wso2-integration-studio

I want to install Rstudio for ubuntu, so I used the link `https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/` after that I choosen `RStudio 0.99.893 - Ubuntu 12.04+/Debian 8+ (64-bit)` then I opened with Ubuntu software center. In that I clicked the `install` button I got error box like this,

```
Requires installation of untrusted packages
This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources.
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Here is a duplicate question:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71962411/installing-r-studio-on-ubuntu-22-04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71962411/installing-r-studio-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Answer (score 0):

The unauthenticated package required by RStudio is libjpeg62, so install the package separately and then install rstudio from software center

In the terminal run the following for installing libjpeg62

```
sudo apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated libjpeg62
```

Then go back to installing rstudio.

Note: you need to install r interpretor along with rstudio this you can do by following

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Answer (score 0):

**# Install R and RStudio on Ubuntu 14.04**

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev

**# Download and Install RStudio**

sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
wget https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-1.0.44-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi rstudio-1.0.44-amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

Runs following commands :

In order to install RStudio on Ubuntu 18.04 we will first need to install the r-base package. Open up terminal and enter:

```
$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt -y install r-base
```

To install DEB file on Ubuntu Linux is by using the gdebi command. 
In case gdebi is not available on your system you can install it by executing the bellow command:

```
$ sudo apt install gdebi-core
```

All Package(builds) are available : in this [link](https://www.rstudio.org/download/daily/desktop/ubuntu64/) or [link](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download). You can select different package.

I had download and install : **rstudio-xenial-1.1.463-amd64.deb** build(package) from above in this [link](https://www.rstudio.org/download/daily/desktop/ubuntu64/).

```
$ wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-dailybuilds/rstudio-xenial-1.1.463-amd64.deb


$ sudo gdebi rstudio-xenial-1.1.463-amd64.deb
```

To Start R-Studdio from following command :

```
$ rstudio
```