# Installing R Studio on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 and R. Now I'm trying to install [R Studio](https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-2022.02.1-461-amd64.deb).

After download it I tried to install with

```
sudo gdebi rstudio-2022.02.1-461-amd64.deb
```

But I received the message

```
Dependency is not satisfiable: libssl1.0.0|libssl1.0.2|libssl1.1
```

Is there any way to work around it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Edit #1: I've solved the dependency problem by going to https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/amd64/libssl1.1/download and installing 'libssl1.1' from there. Unfortunately, I've encountered another problem; I'll post another edit as soon as I've solved it, or if I've given up on trying to solve it.*

*Edit #2: I've solved the aforementioned problem by running `rstudio --no-sandbox` to open RStudio.*

My Original Answer:

This isn't a solution, but I have the same problem. I was missing 'libclang-dev' and 'libpq5' as well, but I was able to get them via `sudo apt install`. I couldn't get 'libssl1.1', however:

```
Package libssl1.1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl1.1' has no installation candidate
```

I tried 'libssl1.0.2' and 'libssl1.0.0' as well, but got the same result. After doing some research and trying out different things, I found that I have 'libssl3'; I suspect that having a more recent version of 'libssl' is related to the problem, but I'm not an expert on this stuff and it could just be a stupid guess for all I know.

Also, when I run `sudo apt install -f ./rstudio-2022.02.1-461-amd64.deb`, I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 rstudio : Depends: libssl1.0.0 but it is not installable or
                    libssl1.0.2 but it is not installable or
                    libssl1.1 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I initially ran `sudo dpkg -i rstudio-2022.02.1-461-amd64.deb`, and I had to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` afterwards; it was after then that I tried and successfully installed the two other missing packages. Yep, I basically don't know what I'm doing and I just try solving these technological problems through trial and error, although I've almost never been as stumped as I am now.

Comment: Thanks John. Downloading  libssl1.1 from Debian repository and running  "--fix-broken install" after "dpkg -i" worked for me. I also took cmhh's suggestion on modifying rstudio.desktop. Thank you all.

Comment: This also worked for me, although I used gdebi - dpkg wouldn't work with Rstudio even with ``--fix-broken-install``

Comment: I used gdebi for installing both libssl1.1 and rstudio. I also added the flag `--no-sandbox` to `/usr/share/applications/rstudio.desktop` file (`Exec` parameter) to be able to use the default desktop icon from the applications search.

Answer (score 18):

So I had the same problem about the "Dependency is not satisfiable",

You can just update Rstudio with the last daily update
https://dailies.rstudio.com/

Comment: Is there a bug report for this that we can upvote?

Comment: Now the wget link is:
`wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb`

They updated the last version number 1.2 to 1.3 (right before "amd64")

Comment: You can also do ```sudo nano ~/.config/RStudio/desktop.ini``` and append under ```[General]``` add the line: ```desktop.renderingEngine=software``` to avoid having to do the --no-sandbox option

Comment: More recently, with 22.04 (Jammy), this satisfies the dependency: `wget -q http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb`.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have a good enough reputation to comment, apparently, so posting an 'answer'.  I have installed RStudio on 22.04 without problem (well, not without problem--I have to add some startup paramters to make it load properly on Wayland).  Here's what APT reports as available for me:

```sh
$ apt-cache search libssl | grep libssl1
```

```
libssl1.1 - Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
```

And it seems to be installed okay:

```sh
$ dpkg -s libssl1.1
```

```
Package: libssl1.1
Status: install ok installed
Priority: important
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 4057
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: openssl
Version: 1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.2
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0
Breaks: isync (<< 1.3.0-2), lighttpd (<< 1.4.49-2), python-boto (<< 2.44.0-1.1), python-httplib2 (<< 0.11.3-1), python-imaplib2 (<< 2.57-5), python3-boto (<< 2.44.0-1.1), python3-imaplib2 (<< 2.57-5)
Description: Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
 This package is part of the OpenSSL project's implementation of the SSL
 and TLS cryptographic protocols for secure communication over the
 Internet.
 .
 It provides the libssl and libcrypto shared libraries.
Homepage: https://www.openssl.org/
Original-Maintainer: Debian OpenSSL Team <pkg-openssl-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
```

Are you able to confirm you have the same candidate package listed?  Maybe your APT sources didn't update correctly?  Here's what's currently in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted                                      

deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted

deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe

deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse

deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
```

If yours is the same, maybe you have something in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` that should have been disabled on upgrade and wasn't?

Comment: My comment about RStudio not working on Wayland is, I imagine, the same issue referred to below which is solved by adding `--no-sandbox`.  In fact, my solution was to add `Exec=/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rstudio --disable-seccomp-filter-sandbox %F` to `/usr/share/applications/rstudio.desktop` so that the icon in the favourites list still works.

Comment: Thanks. I installed Ubunty Jammy in a new computer, so it was not an upgrade. My sources.list is the same as yours. Nevertheless nothing is listed to "apt-cache search libssl | grep libssl1". I have libssl3 instead.

Comment: That's interesting.  I actually installed when it was release candidate (about a week ago), and now I'm wondering whether this is a last minute update between then and the final release.  I notice on my other computer there is no upgrade ready yet.  Maybe mine will break tomorrow!

Comment: Curiously, when you google 'jammy libssl1.1' it returns [https://packages.ubuntu.com/cs/jammy/amd64/libssl1.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cs/jammy/amd64/libssl1.1), and when you follow the link you get an 'error, package not available in this suite' result.

Comment: Downloading libssl1.1 from Debian repository (John's suggestion) and modifying  rstudio.desktop (your solution) worked. R Studio is running now. Thanks

Comment: The `--disable-seccomp-filter-sandbox` parameter added to the desktop file did not work for me. Only the `--no-sandbox` parameter did work.

Comment: RStudio are now doing daily builds for 22.04 which seem to work okay for me. https://dailies.rstudio.com/.

Comment: @cmhh that was my entire problem, I'd upgraded and `/etc/apt/sources.list` was missing `deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe` and
`deb http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is [already solved](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/pull/11074/commits) in the daily code since 27th of April. **Install [any daily](https://dailies.rstudio.com/rstudio/spotted-wakerobin/desktop/jammy/) after that and it works**. No news yet of when stable version will be released though.

Answer (score 1):

This answer worked for me and was very simple: https://askubuntu.com/a/1403683

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl1.1
```

Comment: Careful, this **overwrites** the apt source file. You almost certainly do *not* want to do that. To avoid this, use `tee -a` instead of `tee`.

Comment: Thanks Konrad, not sure what to do now that i've done it

Answer (score 1):

After try a lot,
I installed libssl1.1 looking the latest version in security.debian.org:

wget https://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1n-0+deb11u5_amd64.deb

I got as result:
2023-09-21 10:01:31 (4,11 MB/s) - ‘libssl1.1_1.1.1n-0+deb11u5_amd64.deb.1’ saved [1558508/1558508]

Then,
sudo dpkg -i ./libssl1.1_1.1.1n-0+deb11u5_amd64.deb.1

and finally:
sudo apt install -f ./rstudio-2023.06.1-524-amd64.deb
and it works

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35024532)

Comment: Solved my issues for rstudio server in conda env (WSL ubunut 22)

Answer (score 1):

RStudio Server 2023.09.0-463-amd64

```bash
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/jammy/amd64/rstudio-server-2023.09.0-463-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi rstudio-server-2023.09.0-463-amd64.deb
ip addr show
```

Answer (score 0):

The missing libraries may now be installed from `libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb`, which may now be found on https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/21.10/ubuntu-updtes-main-amd64/.

I have used Arronax to add `--no-sandbox` to the command-line, in `rstudio.desktop`, in place of `--disable-seccomp-filter-sandbox` which did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The stable release for Rstudio only supports Ubuntu 22 after 2022, Jun, 3. So installing previous release may cause the problem.

Quick Answer: To install the required package `libssl1.0.0|libssl1.0.2|libssl1.1`, I used the command `apt install libssl-dev`, I also tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install`.