# RStudio hangs, won't start on Ubuntu 22.04LTS (R compiled from source)

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, rstudio

Just another post about RStudio does not start.

I'm using Ubuntu Linux 22.04LTS "jammy". Since the new R version (currently 4.2.0) wasn't available in the repositories for almost two weeks, I compiled and installed it from source.

Among other things, from [configuring options](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Configuration-options) I chose *with shared libraries* as RStudio desires.

```
./configure --enable-R-shlib
```

I then simply used `make` with the default settings, so that R can be found under `/usr/local/bin/R`.

I'm using both VSCode and RStudio. In VSCode, R works like a charm, while RStudio now won't even start. Since the window won't close and I have to `kill` it, it might be suspended in some sort of endless loop.

[image]

I have no software firewall enabled, and I only have one `libR.so` located at `/usr/local/lib/R/lib/libR.so`.

The "explanations" on community.rstudio.com were not very helpful. Also the official support suggestion [resetting](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State) didn't work, and their explanation how to force RStudio to use a specific R version is [Windows-biased](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488508-RStudio-Desktop-IDE-Will-Not-Start).

I should add that I have also updated Ubuntu to the new version. Actually all settings should have been taken over, but maybe it's an issue with permissions. But then I am not sure which permissions should be changed.

I appreciate any advice on how to solve the problem.

##### Edit

When I start `rstudio` from terminal, I get the empty window shown above, no errors, the following output, and nothing else happens:

```
$ rstudio
TTY detected. Printing informational message about logging 
configuration. Logging configuration loaded from '/etc/xdg/xdg-
ubuntu:/etc/xdg/rstudio/logging.conf'. Logging to '/home
/jay/.local/share/rstudio/log/rdesktop.log'.
```

However:

```
$ cat home/jay/.local/share/rstudio/log/rdesktop.log
cat: home/jay/.local/share/rstudio/log/rdesktop.log: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Which RStudio version are you using exactly? Did you build that from source as well? Or how did you install it?

Comment: @MrFlick It's `2022.02.2+485` installed from the latest Debian package (i.e. not from source).

Comment: It's a known and reported issue with RStudio on 22.04, it has nothing to do with your R build.  (As an aside the Rutter port of my Debian package binary is now at CRAN, and as I tweeted I made Ubuntu binaries available via my PPA the day of the release.  Also keep an eye out on r-sig-debian which is a good list for R on Debian and Ubuntu,

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you for your helpful hints! I assume you are referring to R binaries (not RStudio). Let me know if you have any suggestions on what to do with RStudio now.

Comment: Have you see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71962411/installing-r-studio-on-ubuntu-22-04  ?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have no such error message, just nothing happens. Also see edit.

Comment: Wayland versus xorg, maybe? "It works for me" on Ubuntu 22.04, using a daily (currently at 2022.06.0 Build 343) but I think I switched from Wayland to XOrg.  It's on laptop I don't use much but just fired up to confirm.  I use the standard Ubuntu package for R 4.2.0 (derived from my Debian package).  (And just upgraded to 'Build 351'. Still works.)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel This was the decisive clue, at least for a preliminary solution; I installed the latest development version [2022.06.0-daily+343](https://dailies.rstudio.com/version/2022.06.0-daily+343/) and it works now, thanks! I leave this open for anyone who encounters the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
rstudio --no-sandbox
```

Type this into your terminal and it will boot up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do in terminal AFTER launching and closing rstudio from start menu or terminal:

`sudo nano ~/.config/RStudio/desktop.ini`

APPEND under `[General]`:

`desktop.renderingEngine=software`

to avoid having to do the --no-sandbox option and to enable launch from start menu.

*note: you must have first launched and closed rstudio (from start menu or terminal) before the desktop.ini file is automatically created (even if rstudio hangs the desktop.ini file is created).