# Rstudio not starting on Ubuntu 22.04 - error while loading shared library: libcrypto.so.1.1

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, rstudio

There's a `libcrypto.so.1` in the system, I created a symlink to it as `libcrypto.so.1.1`, but it does not find it.

I'm launching rstudio via the binary download: https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-2022.02.2-485-amd64-debian.tar.gz

Comment: Have you seen my recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72115826/6574038, maybe it helps.

Comment: Different issue. This one doesn't even launch a window.

Answer (score 1):

This fixes it (a problem with packaging in 22.04):

```
wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
```

Comment: 404 Not Found. Can you be more specific about what package and version is missing? I have `libssl-dev` installed and I still have this same problem.

Comment: @Arthur Just browse the files at http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/ and grab the relevant one.